# Probability of not appearing a side of a dice

Tags: probability

We flip over a dice infinite times. What is the probability that a specific side will never show up?
I think that the probability is zero. Am I wrong ?

Comment: It depends whether or not the dice is fair

Comment: I suppose that the dice is fair.

Comment: If dice has $f$ sides, a specific side, say $F$, not appearing on each throw is $\frac{f-1}{f}<1$. Probability of $F$ not appearing after $n$ throws is $\left(\frac{f-1}{f}\right)^n$ and as $n\to \infty$, $\left(\frac{f-1}{f}\right)^n \to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ask you first, what is the probability that a specific side will not appear after 1 flip?
The answer, of course, is $5/6$.  What about after 2 flips?  That means that the first flip is not that side, AND the second flip is not that side.  This probability is then $(5/6)^2$.  Continuing in this fashion, what is the probability that that side will not come up after $n$ flips?  This will be $(5/6)^n$.  To consider what happens after an INFINITE number of flips, we consider $\lim {(5/6)^n}$ as $n \to \infty $.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Of course it helps !! thank you !

Answer (score 1):

A direct corollary of the law of large numbers is that if there is a non-zero probability of event E occurring in a trial, and the number of trials goes to infinity, then E must happen. This, there is zero probability that E won't happen.

Comment: I like this one because it follows more of the "philosophical" approach to this question